# How do I include '/usr/bin' in the PATH environment?

Tags: paths

I did a mistake and I can't do anything white the terminal.

When I try a command it just says:

```
Command 'sudo' is available in '/usr/bin/sudo'
The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
sudo: command not found
```

version 18.04.2 LTS

Comment: Depends upon the mistake. Unless you changed your .bashrc or .profile, restarting the terminal will flush your changed PATH.

Comment: ok how do I restart the terminal?

Comment: If you are using a terminal on a graphical desktop xou close the window and open a new one. If unsure just reboot your PC (yes I know this is rude but easy to do).